# Move a div inside another on browser resize

Tags: html, responsive

I'm currently integrating a website and I have a slight issue dealing with an element that's not at the same place on mobile or on desktop.

Here's the (simplified) code :

```
<div class="div-wrapper">

  <div class="my-text-input">Input</div>

    <div class="map">

      <!-- Content -->

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

So I have "my-text-input" element **outside** the "map" one on mobile (it's mobile-first). When it's displayed on desktop, I'd like it to be placed **inside** the "map" element.

Do you have a clue about how to do it without duplicate content  ? I considered writing the element twice (inside and outside) and displaying one or the other, but I'd like to avoid this solution.

JS/jQuery solutions welcome if needed.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code Sorry for formatting i have issue while posting

```
$(document).ready(function(){
appendDiv();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
 appendDiv();
 });
```

//append div to another on desktop and Tablet view

```
function appendDiv() {
if ($(window).width() > 767) {
$('.my-text-input').detach().appendTo('.map');
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
  // tasks to do if it is a Mobile Device
  $('.map').before('<div class="my-text-input">Input</div>');

}else // for desktop
{
  $('.map').append('<div class="my-text-input">Input</div>');
}
```